# Varying values for histogram max javacv

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to get the maximum value from a histogram that I ran on a picture. My histogram code looks like this: (thanks to a stack overflow user for this)

```
  public static CvHistogram getHueHistogram(IplImage image){

    if(image==null || image.nChannels()<3) new Exception("Error!");

    // Split the 3 channels into 3 images
    IplImageArray hsvChannels = splitChannels(image);

    //bins and value-range
    int numberOfBins=255;
    float minRange= 0f;
    float maxRange= 180f;

    // Allocate histogram object
   int dims = 1;
   int[]sizes = new int[]{numberOfBins};
   int histType = CV_HIST_ARRAY;
   float[] minMax = new  float[]{minRange, maxRange};
   float[][] ranges = new float[][]{minMax};
   int uniform = 1;
   CvHistogram hist = cvCreateHist(dims, sizes, histType, ranges, uniform);

   // Compute histogram
   int accumulate = 1;

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   IplImage mask = null;
   cvCalcHist(hsvChannels.position(0),hist, accumulate, null);
   return hist;
}

private static IplImageArray splitChannels(IplImage hsvImage) {
    CvSize size = hsvImage.cvSize();
    int depth=hsvImage.depth();
    IplImage channel0 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    IplImage channel1 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    IplImage channel2 = cvCreateImage(size, depth, 1);
    cvSplit(hsvImage, channel0, channel1, channel2, null);
    return new IplImageArray(channel0, channel1, channel2);
}
```

Now here is my get max method:

```
public static float getHistMaxValue (CvHistogram hist){

    float[] minValue = {0};// these exist from when I was testing the function, ignore them
    float[] maxValue = {0};
    int[] minId = {0}; // these exist from when I was testing the function, ignore them
    int[] maxId = {0};  
    cvGetMinMaxHistValue( hist, null, maxValue, null, maxId);

    System.out.printf("%2f", maxValue[0]);


    return maxValue[0];
}
```

Now for the most part this works fine, my issue is that my values for max change from 1532,298027, and 298038 each time I run the program, even though the image for the histogram remains the same. I do preform a decent amount of processing on the image before it gets a histogram, but those functions seem to be working properly. Any ideas as to why these results tend to change?

Comment: It seems that `maxValue` is an array. Have you tried printing all of it's values instead of just printing index 0?

Comment: Looking through the debugger, it appears that [0] is the only thing that has a non 0 value. And this time when I ran the program I got 9000 some as the value...

Comment: This is an "image processing" question, not an "image" and "processing" question. The "processing" tag is specifically for the visual programming language called "Processing". It's probably a good idea to remove that tag from your post.